# Event handling in rest api of laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I want to send request to the driver and driver will either accept or reject my request . elements of my request are my location and vehicle_type . currently my code is like that

```
$request=DB::table('request_ride')->get()->toArray();
      return $order;
```

i am just fetching all the request at that time but i want that when i request a ride that certain driver will respond to me and only that data will show and that method i used to add data in 'ride_request' table is that

```
$rules=[
         ......
        ];

        $validator=Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(),400);
        }

        $ride=model::create($request->all());
```

Comment: How do we know anything about drivers or how this relates to a specific request?

Comment: in 'request_ride' table i have an attribute name driver_id

Comment: You might want to formalize a better question as it currently deels like “please build my code”. What have you tried? Or which parts are unclear to you and do you need some help on?

Comment: no i just need some hints regarding this

Comment: You asked this question just now, please only ask once, we are not here to solve your problems, but fix your errors. Please try your self and when you run into errors, tell them to us :)